# Dynamically allocating objects

Tags: class, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

Board *board1 = new Board(*this);
move(board1.tiles_[blankTile + dimensions]);

error: request for member ‘tiles_’ in ‘temp’, which is of non-class type ‘Board*’

I dont understand how board1 is not type Board*. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Board` is a class type, `Board*` is a pointer to a class type.

The problem is that you're using `.` where you should be using `->`.

If you don't understand the difference, you should probably repeat the first chapter on pointers in your fine book.